# Authenticating user by parsing the JSON returned by the WebService

Tags: android, json, parsing, webserver

i have a login page and wanted to get authenticated using web server and after anthenticated user will be able to see home page how to do this in android using json  parser 
please guide me...

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi Sheikh Aman do u have any idea about this thing ???

Comment: I just answered your question. Next time, please come up with a nice title to your questions :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communications between a webserver and a mobile device are mostly stateless.

You send your login credentials to the webserver, It validates you and if you're an authenticated user, it sends you a token/pin. you use this pin for every further communication.

This is how most of the RESTful services work.

Later, you request server for particular information, it returns JSON, you parse that JSON and display the parsed data.

Use [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/) for parsing JSON Data. its nice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the username and password using get or post methods to the webserver using the url.

At the server, you need to validate the username and password by retrieving the details from the database and return the validation status..

No JSON parsing is required for the user validation.